# Divide a circle into smaller circles

Tags: qgis

I would like to divide the brown circle into smaller circles. The brown circle have been computed from the "Minimum enclosing circles" function.

[image]

Is it possible to do it easily on QGIS?

Also, the final objective is to compute a circular representation splitted in quadrants, like this.

[image]

Do you know if it is natively possible to create a representation like this in QGIS (without having to create multiple circles buffers and to make a union on them?)?

Comment: That first circle doesn't look like a minimum enclosing circle given the brown points. Is there another set of points we can't see? Is the full problem to generate a set of radial and distance zones (based on some radius angle interval and distance step) based on the minimum enclosing circle of a set of points?

Comment: The title asks about "smaller citcles" but the Question shows non-circular polygons.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the geometry generator, either as display or as an expression to create a new layer.

It would build an array of buffer length and a buffer of azimuth, then loop over them and build `wedged_buffer` for each quadrant.

If you want to use irregular sizes, replace `generate_series(...)` with `array(0,10,...)`

```
collect_geometries( 
 array_foreach( 
   generate_series(0,5000,1000), -- the buffer sizes, from 0 to 5000 with an increament of 1000
   with_variable(
     'buffer', --Rename the buffer size variable
     @element,
     collect_geometries( 
       array_foreach( 
        generate_series(0,350,10), -- azimut, full circle with a step of 10 degrees
        wedge_buffer(
         $geometry,
         @element,
         10, --same as the azimut step
         @buffer,
         @buffer+1000
        )
       ) 
     )
   )
  )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

in addition to the solution of @JGH you can use the geometry generator to make a automatic minimal enclosing circle around the features and divide it into smaller circles:

```
collect_geometries(
   array_foreach(array(1,1.3,2,4),
      make_circle(
            centroid(
                 minimal_circle( 
                         collect($geometry))),
                                perimeter(minimal_circle( 
                                      collect($geometry)))/(2*pi() )/@element)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot four your solution ! Just a small question, what does the numbers (1, 1.3, 2, 4) represent ? (My goal is to achieve the creation of 32, 16 and 8 smaller circles). Thanks again !

Comment: this is an array to divide the radius for the small circels, in this example we have 4 circles with radius/1, radius/1.3, radius/2 and radius/4 of the outer circle